# Cannot receive UDP Stream from Port 2368 (Linux) C

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp

I'm currently working with a Laser Sensor that delivers a UDP data stream on Port 2368. I can see the packets with Wireshark.

As I'm not able to post an image, I write what Wireshark shows for a packet:

Source: 192.168.17.141
Destination: 192.168.3.255
Protocol: UDP
Source Port: https (443)
Destination Port: opentable (2368)

However, I want to read the packets using sockets with following example C program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sock, n, res;
   unsigned int length = 1206;
   char* buffer = new char[1206];  

   sock= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if (sock < 0) error("socket");

   uint16_t udp_port = 2368;
   sockaddr_in my_addr;                    
   socklen_t len = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
   memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));   
   my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;           
   my_addr.sin_port = htons(udp_port);    
   my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

   cout << my_addr.sin_family << endl;
   cout << my_addr.sin_port << endl;
   cout << my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr << endl;


   res = bind(sock, (sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
   if (res == -1)
     {
       perror("bind");                 
       return -1;
     }


   while (true)
   {
       n = recvfrom(sock,buffer,1,0,NULL,NULL);
       if (n < 0) error("recvfrom");
   }

   close(sock);
   return 0;
}
```

The program is successful until it comes to `recvfrom()`. There the socket waits for packages and does not receive anything. I wrote the same program for Windows with Winsock and it worked perfectly. As I am relatively new to Linux OS I do not know how to fix this problem and would be thankful for advice!

Additional information: I manually assigned following IP and netmask to eth4 (this is the interface where the device is connected):

IP: 192.168.3.5
NM: 255.255.255.0

Comment: Your program is C++, not C, as you use the `cout` variable, part of the C++ class iostream.

Comment: 192.168.3.255 would be a broadcast address with netmask 255.255.255.0 , you usually have to enable the SO_BROADCAST socket option to receive those packets. But if 192.168.17.141 sends to your machine, it cannot send to the broadcast address of your /24 network, so there must be some mixups with the netmask here.

Comment: You are expecting 1-octet sized packets?

Answer (score 1):

Set the SO_BROADCAST option, even for receiving.  According to the socket(7) manpage:

> SO_BROADCAST:
>   Set  or  get  the broadcast flag.  When enabled, datagram sockets ***receive packets sent to a broadcast address*** and they are allowed to send packets to a broadcast address.  This option has no effect on stream-oriented sockets.

It could also be that your interface config is incorrect.  Verify that you have a 192.168.3.xxx/24 address configured for the interface in question.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
IP: 192.168.3.5 NM: 255.255.255.0
```

and

```
Source: 192.168.17.141 Destination: 192.168.3.255
```

This can't work, if there is no router involved. Try

```
IP: 192.168.3.5 NM: 255.255.0.0
```

as an interims measure, but do read up on IP

Edit: Maybe better look into your Laser sensor and set it to `192.168.3.[something free]` with Destination directly your `192.168.3.5`, and debug the broadcasting later.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately changing the sensor's IP is not possible! I also tried your suggested configuration but with no success.

Comment: If the Sensor's IP can't be changed, you could change your Destination and your Linux host's IP to be in the 192.168.17.x range. If this isn't possible also you need a broadcast enabled router. Which IP settings did you use on Windows?

Comment: I used the same settings as described above (192.168.3.5, 255.255.255.0) for my windows application and it worked fine. I just set my IP to 192.168.17.5, but I still don't receive any packages. Is it possible that something is blocking port 2368?

Comment: @user1156079 You should change the netmask on your linux PC to 255.255.0.0 , not the IP. If this is still a no-go, you should try to set the socketoption SO_BROADCAST on the socket ( `int bcast = 1; if(setsockopt(your_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &bcast, sizeof bcast) == -1) {perro("setsockopt");}` )

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[1200+6]; /* no need for dynamic buffers */
...
n = recvfrom(sock, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

BTW your usage of recvfrom() is equivalent to

```
n = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0);
```

, or even:

```
n = read(sock, buffer, sizeof buffer);
```